# Jquery date picker not functioning in jsp

Tags: jsp

I'm using date picker jquery plugin for one of the form field.but the function is not working.The jsp code and js  snippet is as below

```
   <input type="text" class="form-input datepicker"
                        name="_orderdate" placeholder="Order Date" 
                        style="height: 45px; width: 90%" />


    $(function() {
$( "#_orderdate" ).datepicker({
   showOn:"button",
   buttonImage: "css/calendar.png",
   buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

});

Any pointers to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**your jquery function is using the id attribute and your input field id attribute is missing**

The input field must be like

```
       <input type="text" class="form-input datepicker" id="_orderdate"
                        name="_orderdate" placeholder="Order Date" 
                        style="height: 45px; width: 90%" />
```